# Getting error in Pandas as: IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting the error as below.
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

I need the index defined in Dataframe below to have variable length as my Dataframe can have variable size. If I remove the index, I get the error mentioned above.
I tried looking into past solutions but I did not find anything suitable for my code. Please help

BatsmanRanking = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3,4], columns = ["Batsman","Runs","Balls"]
Expected output is a dataframe with rows and columns

Comment: index 0 is the first element.  If a dataframe is empty, then it doesn't have a first element.  Before trying to access index 0, you should check if the dataframe is empty.

Comment: Dataframe is empty. How can I add entries to an empty dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer your question since you haven't posted any code, but it sounds like you're trying to build some function that might take an empty DataFrame. What you can do is add a check at the beginning to see if len(df) > 0, return if false, proceed if true. For example:

```
def some_function(potentially_empty_df):
  if len(potentially_empty_df) == 0:
    return
  else:
    // Do other stuff
```